# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

i am using entity framework and storage process and crystal report

i wanna get storage process and view it in crystal report

but i  get this error

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

inner exception
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.Fields.get()
```

this is storage process

```
USE [PayRoll]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SR1]    Script Date: 12/09/2020 15:41:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SR1]

As
BEGIN

SELECT         
                         EmployeeCode,EmployeeName,JopName,Date_Hiring,Nat_Salary
FROM            
                         Employee_List_Code_Name_Jop_DateHiring 
END
```

and this is Code to call storage process
error show here  rpt.SetDataSource(bs);

```
            if(Report_Number == "2")
            {
                var Employee_Data = db.Database.SqlQuery<Table>("EXEC SR1").ToList();
                bs.DataSource = Employee_Data;
            }
            //
            //
            //
            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
            rpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Report\\Arabic\\" + "R" + Report_Number + ".rpt");

            rpt.SetDataSource(bs);
```

and this storage process class

```
namespace PayRoll.database
{
    using System;
    
    public partial class SR1_Result
    {
        public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string JopName { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date_Hiring { get; set; }
        public double Nat_Salary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

how  can fixed this error??

Answer (score 0):

i get error in sql query

replace

SqlQuery

SqlQuery<SR1_Result>

like this

```
if(Report_Number == "2")
            {
                var Employee_Data = db.Database.SqlQuery<SR1_Result>("SR1").ToList();
                bs.DataSource = Employee_Data;
            }
```